# Installing a Gnome-Shell extension (Ubuntu)

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, gnome-shell-extension

I've an extension composed by the following files:

[image]

and I'm wondering how can I install it.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

---

EDIT: I tried to install it by copying and pasting the js file into the terminal.
Then I tried to search some tutorial about how to install js file extension, but all the results I got are about node.js.

Comment: For who downvotet, please specify why.

Comment: Not me but my guess is because you haven't specified what you have tried so far and what the results were to save duplication of effort. Read [ask] for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @24601

Comment: Did you read the manual of whatever extension you are trying to install in this particular way? You copied and pasted the file in the terminal? How did you manage to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found a tutorial to install extensions of the Gnome-Shell.

1. Log into the Linux device
2. Execute the following commands in a terminal in order to install gnome tweaks:

   ```
        # install gnome tweaks utility
        sudo apt update
        sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
        # create the extensions directory
        mkdir /.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions -p
        # output the gnome shell version
        gnome-shell --version
   ```
3. Open a web browser and navigate to https://extensions.gnome.org/
4. Search for an extension to install and select it
5. From the Shell version... dropdown select the closest version to the installed gnome shell version output earlier
6. Select the latest version available from the Extension version... dropdown
7. Save the extension .zip file
8. Open a file manager and navigate to ~/Downloads
9. Extract the downloaded extension .zip file
10. Browse the extracted folder contents and edit metadata.json in a text editor
11. Copy the value of UUID key
12. Close the text editor
13. Navigate back one directory
14. Cut the entire extracted extension directory to ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
15. Restart Gnome Shell by logging out and logging back in
16. Launch Gnome Tweaks
17. Select Extensions from the left navigation menu
18. The newly installed extension should be listed
19. Enable the extension and enjoy